# Chossing between azure tables and documentdb

Tags: azure

We have application where we need to store data with one schema in large quantities (>1*10^6 rows). We have limited transactions and mostly read. We can choose for DocumentDB or Azure Tables. I am new on DOcumentDB. What are benefits on using documentDB over Azure Tables

Comment: You should start with the documentation on the Azure site. You're asking the differences between a key/value store and a document store. They both have significantly different query abilities, pricing models, and performance. Then ask specific programming questions about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of difference on using DocumnentDB and Azure Table.

It is mostly depending on the datastructure you have and how you want to interact with your data. The benefits of documentdb over Azure Table that I find important are:

- DocumentDB allow for very complex data structures, including hierarchical datastructures. For instance Order and Orderlines in one document
- DocumentDB allows the creation of serverside stored procedures, UDFs and  Triggers. This allows the ability to put login into the datalayer.
- DocumentDB is pure JSON in and Out. You add, update and retrieve JSON documents and do not have to make transformations to other classes.
- DocumentDB allows complex Queries on complex data structures in the JSON. You can query on for Order that have a certain product in the orderline.

Hope that this helps.
Sander